# How does October CMS use other sites to log in?

Tags: octobercms

I have multiple sites (built in different frameworks), one of which was built using the October CMS. Now to do single sign-on, my question is how does Octo CMS access single sign-on?

Comment: Hm, I don't understand your question. Can you explain a little more?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I can't speak English well! I have multiple sites (built in different frameworks), one of which was built using the October CMS. Now to do single sign-on, my question is how does Octo CMS access single sign-on?